# Killing activities before they stack, so recalling an activity doesn't cause an overflow

Tags: android, android-activity, stack-overflow, return

I have read into the `finish();` commands and the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` commands and also checked out Common Ware's answer on killing app, but I am not sure how to put this into my app.

Basically, I have a user click a button that takes them to the camera. The user then snaps a photo and it brings them to a layout view. The user then clicks a button that takes them to one of 2 views, depending on a some conditions.

The user is then allowed to either retake a photo, or go to the main menu (depending). My problem is, if the user goes back to the main menu, and snaps another, then another, etc...the activities stack, so when I click the 'Main Menu' button the app goes back through eached stack activity until finally it goes back to the main menu. Is there a way to kill each activity with one of these lines, so even if a user retakes a photo, they will only need to go back once to get to the main menu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `noHistory` parameter in the manifest to accomplish this. Here is an example of a manifest entry for a Activity that should not be placed in the history stack:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:label="MyActivityTitle"
          android:noHistory="true" />
```

Comment: Well technically my main class is one activity that uses multiple methods to snap and detect photos...so if I enter that into the manifest then after a new method is called it closes the app.

Comment: In that case, you should just override the back button do whatever you want.